# Lifespan of Launchpad-Launched Exterrnal Runtime Processes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, python, r, sql-server-2017

When SQL Server uses SQL Launchpad to launch an external runtime (e.g. R or Python) when `sp_execute_external_script` is used, what's the lifespan of the external runtime process?

Does each `sp_execute_external_script` script execution get its own external process instance or does the external process stay around until it's been inactive for a certain amount of time (e.g. the existing process might be reused if I execute another script written in the same language using the same SQL session)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, Python processes are not reused. **Each call to `sp_execute_external_script` uses its own process instance(s)**, at least as far as Python goes.

Since Microsoft SQL Server's Python and R integrations are *very similar*, I'd *suspect* the same holds true with R, as well, but I can't say that with 100% certainty.

Reference: [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Database/comments/78on91/were_tobias_and_travis_pms_on_the_sql_server/dovlik9/?st=j98rywqw&sh=abfca912) made by SQL Server engineering team program manager Tobias Ternström